# Are there further ideas for a repair of a 3.3V -> 5V shorted pi?

Tags: pi-3b+, power-supply, boot-issues

I accidentally shorted my pi's (3 B+) 3.3V and 5V GPIO-Pins.
I was curious how to repair it and found this helpful [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96040/shorted-3-3v-5v-together-is-it-possible-to-repair/114289#114289). So I reworked the pi as described: Removed the broken MXL7704-R3, soldered a new one and checked the voltages. They are as indicated in the image (1.2V 3.3V, 1.8V and 1.2V). To i guess i successfully replaced the MXL7704. But still, the Pi doesn't boot...

What are other typical faults that i could check and maybe lead to a repair of my Pi?

Comment: This is impossible because the Pi uses a custom PMIC.

Comment: Any references to the custom PMIC might be helpful in order to configure the MxL7704 accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, most cost effective, and quickest repair is to buy a new Pi.